# Change Image Frame Width IF image Width = 200

Tags: ios, api, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, imageview

I need to change `cell.image.frame` to `CGRectMake(105, 110, 10, 180)` if the image width I get back from the API is **200**.

Currently any size image I get I have at `CGRectMake(0, 140, 320, 180)`.

So I just need to change the `cell.image.frame` only in the cases where the image width I get back is exactly 200.

I need help figuring out **where to put the `if` statement**, and **what exactly to put in the `if` statement**.

I can't seem to get it to work, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Below is the code:

WebListCell.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 140, 320, 180);   
}
```

WebListViewController.m

```
Images *imageLocal = [feedLocal.images objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageLocal.url];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.gif"]
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
        {
        // Code
        }];
```

Edit: I've tried putting this inside of the `//Code` part:

```
if(imageWith == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"200"])
         {
           cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(105, 110, 10, 180);
         }
```

But it didn't work and also gave me a warning about capturing the cell strongly could lead to retain cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to check the image width makes no sense. You want:

```
if(image.size.width == 200) {
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(105, 110, 10, 180);
}
```

Update: To deal with the problem with the retain cycle you want something like this:

```
__weak UITableViewCell *weakcell = cell;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.gif"]
                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if(image.size.width == 200) {
        weakcell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(105, 110, 10, 180);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That makes a lot more sense, sorry I made no sense before.  I'm still getting the warning about it "capturing the cell strongly in block could lead to retain cycle", any ideas on that?  It's messing something up, because the frame of the picture width is fine initially, then once I start scrolling past the cell, it reverts to the unwanted picture width and stays that way.  Thanks!

Comment: See my updated answer to deal with the retain cycle.

Comment: That definitely helped remove the warning, but it still does the same thing where if I click and hold on the cell and then release, the picture changes size.  That make sense at all?

Comment: I'm guessing its reloading the cell on any touch and hold, and somehow not using the same if parameters that sized it before?

Answer (score 1):

You should put if statement inside completion block, because only there you have an image resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I updated the question to show you what I had previously tried in the completion block that didn't work.  Any suggestions on why what I did didn't work?  Thanks for the help!